# Find entity with many-to-one relationship uses wrong id for query parameter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Look guys, I need some help with Room on Android.

In my project there are two entities, Item and Unit of Measure. The item can be in only one unit of measure but the unit of measure can be in several units.

As the project's interest is to deal with the Item, it would need to have a many-to-one relationship and as Room doesn’t deal with that, I chose to set up a many-to-many relationship and create just one Entity for cross-reference that present the meaning contrary.

The database is already started with 4 units of measurement, Kg, g, L and cm, so the total number of records is 4, the ids are 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

When I insert the first item in the database with a Unit of Measure equal to Kg, it will have Id = 1 (because it was the first record) and when I search for it informing id 1, everything is ok, it works perfectly, it returns the item with the Unit of Measure Kg.

When I register the second item (so now this new item will have id 2) also with the Unit of Measurement equal to Kg there, problems begin to appear. When performing his search informing his id which is 2 he returns the item but as the Unit of Measure equal to g (gram) which is also code 2.

That is, when Room is going to mount the result of the item searched for, the Code of the Unit of Measure is being considered the same code as the Item.

Room doesn't seem to be looking at the id of the relationship I created for the Item with Unit of Measure, but I'm not doing it right, or I'm the one who forgot something.

**ItemEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "item"
)
data class ItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    var itemID: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String = "",
    @ForeignKey(
        entity = ComparationEntity::class,
        parentColumns = ["comparation_id"],
        childColumns = ["fk_comparation_id"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_comparation_id")
    var fkComparationID: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    private var price: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    var quantity: Double = 0.0,
    @Ignore
    private var priceUnit: Double = 0.0
) {

    fun setPrice(price: Double) {
        if (this.quantity.toFloat() != 0.00f && price.toFloat() != 0.00f) {
            priceUnit = this.price.div(this.quantity)
        }
    }

    fun getPrice() = price

    fun getPriceUnit(): Double {
        return priceUnit
    }

}
```

**UnitMeasureEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "unit_measure"
)
data class UnitMeasureEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "un_meas_id")
    var unMeasID: Long = 0,
    val description: String,
    val acronym: String,
    val symbol: String
```

)

**RelationItemWithUnits**

```
@Entity(tableName = "relation_item_whit_units", primaryKeys = ["item_id", "un_meas_id"])
data class RelationItemWithUnits(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    val itemID : Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "un_meas_id")
    val unMeasID : Long
)
```

**ItemWithUnitMeasure**

```
data class ItemWithUnitMeasure(
    @Embedded
    var item: ItemEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = UnitMeasureEntity::class,
        parentColumn = "item_id",
        entityColumn = "un_meas_id",
        associateBy = Junction(RelationItemWithUnits::class)
    )
    var unitMeasureWithMeasureType: UnitMeasureWithMeasureType
)
```

**RelationsUnitsWithMeasuresType**

```
@Entity(tableName = "relation_units_whit_measure_type", primaryKeys = ["un_meas_id", "measure_type_id"])
data class RelationsUnitsWithMeasuresType(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "un_meas_id")
    val unMeasID: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "measure_type_id")
    val measureTypeID : Long
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> it would need to have a many-to-one relationship and as Room doesn’t deal with that, I chose to set up a many-to-many relationship and create just one Entity for cross-reference that present the meaning contrary

I think you've got into misconception there. [Room's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) really doesn't include any `many-to-one` relations. But `many-to-one` relation is the same as `one-to-many` in table's structure sense. Let's say you have table `A` and table `B`, and table `A` has **many** rows with the same **id** from the table `B`. As such tables hold `one-to-many` relation.

1. If you want to get all rows from `A` table and to attach there value from `B` table, you can use [one-to-one relation from Room's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one). Since one row from `A` has a relation only with one row from `B`.
2. If you want to get all rows from `B` table and to attach list of binded values from `A` table, you can use [one-to-many relation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many). Since one row from `B` table has a relation with many rows from `A`.

So you don't need to use separate table and `many-to-many` relations here.
It would be much easier just to add `unitMeasureId` to `ItemEntity` table and then use [one-to-one relation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one) to get needed result.